# Trouble with understanding routing priority

Tags: java, playframework, routes

I am building some sort of discussion board, where you can ask questions and write answers. Now I ran into a problem with routing and seem to be understanding them wrong.

I have a homepage called `index`, from there you can click a button "Ask question" or another button "Write Answer". Each button leads to another webpage (askQuestion.scala.html or writeAnswer.scala.html) where you can write a question or answer. After hitting `submit` you come back to the index-page, where the new question or answer is put into the view. In the background, the question / answer gets put into a DB.

My **routes.conf**:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

#Questions
GET     /FrageStellen               controllers.Application.askQuestion()
POST    /                           controllers.Application.sendQuestion()

#Answers
GET     /AntwortGeben               controllers.Application.writeAnswer()
POST    /                           controllers.Application.sendAnswer()
```

But when I enter an answer, it gets written into the question-table in the DB! This is due to the fact that the question-route is higher up in the routing table and therefore it seems to get selected first.

This is against my understanding of routes, I thought a route consists of a 3-tuple: `HTTP-Method, Request Path, Call definition` ... and as the call definitions differ (sendQuestion() and sendAnswer()), the correct one should be used?

Why is this not the case?

I've read about routing in the [documentation of the play framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting) and googled, but still dont understand.

I am also aware how to fix my problem, but I want to understand what's happening here.

**Fix 1:**
Change this

```
POST    /                           controllers.Application.sendAnswer()
```

to this

```
POST    /Antwort                    controllers.Application.sendAnswer()
```

Disadvantage: This is not the homepage (index) anymore. Seems weird.

**Fix 2:**
Write a combined method for sending stuff from the form to the index.

Disadvantage: I want to keep the methods separate, in order to maintain a better structure in my project. Also I would have to see if a question gets asked or an answer written and based on that omit one of the fields or use another one (answer has an extra questionID-field to link an answer to a question).

So, why is this happening in the routes and whats the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Play each route is combination of route method (`GET`/`POST`) and path (determined by static parts and params types) so if you have two routes with the same type and path **only first** will be resolvable, other will be ignored even if you'll use other name of param (but same param type).

In this case the `bar(String bar)` method **won't** be resolved ever:

```
GET  /foo/:foo controllers.Application.foo(foo: String)
GET  /foo/:bar controllers.Application.bar(bar: String)
```

The safest way to make sure that you won't mishmash the routes is using unique paths always in sets:

```
GET     /                 controllers.Application.index()

GET     /FrageStellen     controllers.Application.askQuestion()
POST    /FrageStellen     controllers.Application.sendQuestion()

GET     /AntwortGeben     controllers.Application.writeAnswer()
POST    /AntwortGeben     controllers.Application.sendAnswer()
```

Finally if you want to go to the root page after post you can return a `redirect()` instead of `ok()`

Comment: So I also have to watch out for the params. This was a really hard to find problem in my project, as my pretty similar routes kind of worked and produced at least some results altough not the intended ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should post to an action with different request path and then redirect to index. It is a recommended approach in web development.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Thanks for the read, very interesting. BUT I'm still curious wether a route is a 2 or 3-tuple. `HTTP-Method, Request Path` or `HTTP-Method, Request Path, Call definition`, as is seems that the action method / call definition does not affect the routing priority.
Sidenote: They mention the PRG on the [Scala-Forms page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms), but NOT on the [Java-Forms page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms)